# Почему — уезд?

Tags: этимология

Задумалась: а почему административная единица в царской России называлась "уезд"? Почему от слова "уезжать", а не, например, "приезжать" или "проезжать"? Как-то пессимистично звучит)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такое мнение:

Историк С.Соловьев объясняет происхождение этого слова от способа межевания земли. Межевщик отделял землю, которая должна была принадлежать или быть приписана к определенному городу, и, поэтому, после размежевания, эта земля как бы – уезжала. Вот что такое уезд – емко, точно и коротко наши предки сформулировали термин, который просуществовал до 20 века.

http://ote4estvo.ru/eto-interesno/1190-chto-takoe-uezd.html

Answer (score 2):

Уезд первоначально - эта та территория, которую объезжал феодал для сбора себе налогов. Что дали "уездить", с того свой кусок и урывает.

Comment: Откуда инфа? И кто такой феодал в Российской глубинке? Помещик? Это не совсем то...

Comment: Уезд впервые упоминается в Уставной грамоте Смоленской (XII век). Включал город и присоединённые к нему волости. Управлялся княжеским наместником.

Comment: А феодал-то кто? Князь?

Comment: В данном случае князь-наместник, который вознаграждался за службу путем кормлений, с того самого уезда, которым владел.

Comment: Ну нехай будет. Меня просто всегда смущал термин "феодал" по отношению к власть имущим на Руси. 
По сути - ничего не могу сказать. Сомнительно как-то...
Надо бы "объезд", "объездить". 
Правда, помнится, в древности у приставки "У" было несколько другое значение, но подходит ли оно тут - не знаю. Похожих слов не могу вспомнить.
Интересно сопоставить эту версию с Соловьевской хотя бы по датам...

Comment: В сущности, феодал русский и феодал западноевропейский мало чем отличаются. До татаро-монгольского нашествия, уникальность русской культуры, вообще, найти довольно проблематично.

В польском ujazd как раз "законный объезд земельного угодья с целью установления его границ", на что в частности ссылается Фасмер. Ключевский также придерживается этой версии, - "Этимология этого термина («уезд») объясняется  одним  административно-судебным  отправлением: полюдьем или ездом; древний администратор сам собирал корм с управляемого округа, объезжая его..."

Comment: >В сущности, феодал русский и феодал западноевропейский мало чем отличаются   
  
Европейский (и не только) феодализм как государственное устройство - это вассальная система. Её никогда не было на Руси, даже удельные княжества имели автономию, граничащую с суверенитетом. В остальном власть всегда была либо удноуровневой, либо наоборот строго вертикальной. Так что собственно феодализма никогда не было. Была т.н. феодальная раздробленность, но даже она заметно отличалась от и европейской и от азиатской схемы.   
Ладно, это не здесь это обсуждать.

Comment: Так таже Бургундия или Аквитания, тоже были фактически самостоятельными государствами, со своей лестницей вассалов. Тоже самое и на Руси. Был Великий Князь Владимирский. Были Владимирское, Новгородское, Киевское княжество, которым подчинялись князья поменьше (вологодское, псковское, московское). При этом и у тех и у других были бояре, князья-наместники, у каждого из выше перечисленных была своя армия. Но это если хотите можно обсудить в личке.

Answer (score 1):

Даю уточнение к ответу Людмилы, в комментраии не лезет.

*Название У., по объяснению С. М. Соловьева, происходит от способа размежевания, именуемого разъездом; межевщик назывался разъезжиком или заездником, а для самого межевания существовал термин разъезжать. По этому термину все количество земли, примежеванное к известному пункту, было уехано к нему, или заехано, являлось его уездом. Наоборот, все то, что было отписано, отмежевано от него, было отъехано, составило отъездные волости.*

(С) БиЭ

В такой формулировке я согласен. Цитируемое Людмилой (уезжающие земли) - выгдлядит несколько фантасмагорично и этимологически, и семантически.

//===============
**Во как!**

Приставка у- в одном из значений, том что придаёт завершенность действия,  оказывается восходит к наречию у, которое продило и современно "ужЕ"-"у+же" , же здесь усилительная частица.

**Но!!!**

II уже́

уж, народн. ужо́ "потом, позднее, также в качестве угрозы", укр. уже́, вже, др.-русск. уже, русск.-цслав. ю "уже, теперь", не ю "еще не" (Григ. Наз., ХI в.; см. Срезн. III, 1625), ст.-слав. оу ἀλλά (Супр.), не оу οὔπω (Клоц., Супр.), оуже ἤδη (Остром., Супр.), наряду с юже (редко в Супр.), болг. уж, сербохорв. диал. jу̏р "уже", словен. užè, urè "уже", др.-чеш. juž, чеш. již, слвц. už, польск. już, в.-луж. hižo, juž, н.-луж. južo, južor.

В вост.-слав. фонетически совпали два и.-е. слова: 1) праслав. *ju(že), родственное лит. jaũ "уже", лтш. jàu, др.-прусск. iau, далее – гот. ju "уже"; см. Бернекер I, 457; Эндзелин, СБЭ 199, Lett. Gr. 479; М.–Э. 2, 96 исл.; Траутман, ВSW 106; Арr. Sprd. 345; Бругман, Grdr. 2, 3, 987. Затем здесь представлено:* 2) праслав. *u, родственное греч. αὖ "с другой стороны, опять-таки", лат. аut "или", гот. аuk "ведь, но"; см. Мейе, МSL 9, 49 и сл.; IFAnz. 7, 164; Мейе–Вайан 42. К последнему относится и ст.-слав., др.-русск. оубо οὖν (относительно -бо см. выше), ср. также диал. ужа́ "прочь, не мешай!", арханг. (Подв.).*
(Фасмер, курсив мой - b-s).

Если предположить, что второе значение наречия "у" (уже), относящее к *разным сторонам*, сохранилось к моменту появления термина "уезд", то значение становится понятным. *Уезд* - это то же, что *разъезд* в значении "разъезжаться" (не разъезжать).
Межа - место, где *разъезжались* по разные стороны. И "уезд", "уездные земли" - это не в смысле уехать или уездить, а те, которые "уезжаются" т.е. разъезжаются, расходятся подобно, скажем, одежде по шву...

Версия, разумеется.       
Но она объясняет все нестыковки двух предыдущих. Имхо.

Answer (score 0):

У Крылова:

<<Это название старинной административной единицы. В польском находим родственное ujazd – "объезд земель для установления их границ". Восходит к той же основе, что и езда.>>

А польские порядки временами были на Руси в большом авторитете. И словечки польские приживались, примеров немало. Вот Вам и "фантазии", вот и  <<при чем тогда "ездить">>.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже Фасмер. Коротко и ясно. Польское - явно.

уе́зд

род. п. -а, др.-русск. уѣздъ (грам. 1318 г.; см. Срезн. III, 1346 и сл.., ср. также Унбегаун 117), польск. ujazd "законный объезд земельного угодья с целью установления его границ" (ХIV в.), также местн. н. Ujazd; см. Соловьев, Энц. Слов. 69, 134 и сл.; Брюкнер 202, 593. Из *u- (у III) и *jězdъ (см. езда́, е́хать); ср. Желтов, ФЗ, 1876, вып. I, стр. 21; Горяев, ЭС 390.